# Laravel migrate:fresh lost all data

Tags: laravel, migration

I had an issues with the last migration. I needed to rerun it, but it told me "nothing to migrate".

I have done some research and found that migrate fresh will reset the migrates, so I can run it again.

But it seems that I missunderstood what it does. It recreated the whole db and deleted everything...

What now? It was a dev DB, but recreating everything will take hours now.

Is there a way to reverse it?

Comment: Sadly, but no way to return if you don't backup when you migrate

Comment: Unless you had some security backup I fear that data is lost